# Error handling Apollo-client with redux-observable

Tags: reactjs, redux-observable, apollo-client

I'm doing a mutation using Apollo-client and redux-observable and so far this is my code:

```
export const languageTimeZoneEpic = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType('PING')
    .flatMap(action => client.mutate({
      mutation: languageTimeZoneIdMutation,
      variables: { id: action.id,  defaultLanguage: action.selected_language, defaultTimeZoneId: action.selected_timeZone }
    })
      .then(store.dispatch(setLocale(action.selected_language)))
  )
    .map(result => ({
      type: 'PONG',
      payload: result
    }))
    .catch(error => ({
      type: 'PONG_ERROR'
    }));
};
```

My mutation works correctly but I can't seem to make my `catch(error)` work. In the small amount of documentation I've found on this, it suggests I put `Observable of` after **error =>** but then it gives me an error saying **Observable** is *undefined*.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

If the connection between the app and the server doesn't work, it just waits for the connection to come back up and then finish the epic. I would like for it to just catch and error and stop the epic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out there was nothing wrong with the `catch(error)` in the code above. Turns out putting the server on hold did not throw an **error** when I tried to establish a connection. It had to be shut down for it to throw an error.

For those who are looking for a good way to implement a mutation using *Apollo-client* with *redux-observable* (because there is almost no docs on it), here's the code I used for my mutation:

```
import { languageMutation } from '../mutation/languageMutation';
import { changeLanguageFulfilled, changeLanguageError } from '../actions/actions';


export const languageEpic = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType('CHANGE_LANGUAGE')
    .mergeMap(action => client.mutate({
      mutation: languageMutation,
       variables: { id: action.id,  defaultLanguage: action.selected_language, defaultTimeZoneId: action.selected_timeZone }
    }).then(result => changeLanguageFulfilled(result))
      .catch(error => changeLanguageError(error))
  );
};
```

Both changeLanguageFulfilled and changeLanguageError are actions that trigger their own reducer.

Hope this helps someone.